# Find row in a table , given I'm looking a value on a column. XPATH

Tags: html, xpath

I'm trying to find the row of a table, given I'm looking for a value in a column. After I have the row value then I can access other columns in the row. I have already know how to do that , but it's not satisfying for me. I'm looking for suggestions.

I have a table with rows that look like this one :

```
<table data-qa="reportTable">
    <tr class="even">
        <td style="">Testing</td>
        <td>2019-11-21 00:00:00.0</td>
        <td>2019-11-24 00:00:00.0</td>
        <td>
            <a href="Some URL" class="followLink">1</a>
        </td>
        <td>$1500.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get the

```html
<a></a>
```

, the url.

I have tried the following :

```xml
//table[@data-qa="reportTable"]//tr[td[1]="Testing"]//a[@class="followLink"]
```

1. I select the table.
2. Then look for the row , the index is defined by step 3.
3. Look for the content in a column , and get the index.
4. Look for the URL.

Assume the value I'm looking for is always on 1.
After I find the value on 1 , then I look for the row , and then get "Some URL"
At the end I need the URL.

I just want to know if there is a better idea to do this, since it looks messy, any idea is appreciated. I already took a look in other solutions but all look the same.

Thanks!

Comment: It would depend a lot on the structure of your table; for example, is the target value (Testing) always in the first `<td>`? Also, what are you trying to select exactly - `"Some URL"` or `1`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm trying to get  ***Some URL*** based on the content in '<td>'  which is always on 1 on this case.

Comment: One more option `//table[@data-qa="reportTable"]//td[normalize-space(.)="Testing"]/parent::tr//a[@class="followLink"]`. Adding normalize-space will make sure if the text is having any white spaces at the beginning or at the end of the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this `xpath` to fetch the required content irrespective of index:

```
//*[@data-qa='reportTable']//tr[td[.='Testing']]//a[@class='followLink']
```

Comment: I didn't knew that could be done, works like charm, I it looks clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

regardless of index, you can you this xpath to get the  URL.

```
//table[@data-qa="reportTable"]/tr[td[text()="Testing"]]/td/a[@class="followLink"]
```

or if your Testing always comes before your , you can use this.

```
//table[@data-qa="reportTable"]/tr/td[preceding-sibling::td[text()="Testing"]]/a[@class="followLink"]
```

Comment: I think it's a really good improvement over my solution , Jack Fleeting left me thinking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This xpath expression:

```
//table[@data-qa="reportTable"]//td[1][text()="Testing"]/following-sibling::td/a/@href
```

selects

> Some URL

Comment: I have never used following-sibling , that will save me some time next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following xpath as well.

```
//table[@data-qa='reportTable']//td[text()='Testing']/parent::tr//td/a/@href
```

Here I am trying to find the table, look for the column that has text 'Testing', fetching the row for this column and then finding 'a' in the other columns in the same row in order to get href.

Hope you find it useful.